NextAuth Update User Session
  useEffect(() => {
    // Check if token exists
    if (token && typeof token === "string") {
      async function handleUpdate() {
        try {
          const response = await apiClient.get(`/auth/update-email?token=${token}`);

          if (!response.error) {
            {
             // Update Session here

              setSuccess(true);

              redirect(callbackUrl || "/account");
            }
          } else {
            !success && setError(response.error);
            
          }
        } catch (err) {
          console.error("Error verifying email: ", err);
          {
            !success && setError("Internal server error");
          }
        }
      }

      handleUpdate();
    } else {
      !success && setErrorsetError("Invalid Token");
    }
  }, [token, callbackUrl]);

Thats my page
The page updates the user's email, but when I go back to this URL which is set to only work if the current session has an session.user.email == null, it still  lets me access it, so how do I update the session so it knows email isnt null anymore?
